# Implementing a list with unique_ptr<>?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

As I understand it, a `unique_ptr` signifies exclusive ownership. A singly linked list seems to fit this, with each node owning the next, like (pseduocode alert)

```
class node{
public:
      unique_ptr<node> next;
      int value;
};
```

but I don't understand how to perform operations like traversing the list, where I'm used to doing

```
here=here->next;
```

How do you implement data structures using `unique_ptr`'s? Are they the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you go through the nodes, you don't need to own the node pointer, which means that

> here=here->next;

Is incorrect if here is a unique_ptr.
Owning an object means "being responsible for it's life and death" which means the owner is the one who have the code that will destroy the object. If you use another definition of owning, then it's not what unique_ptr means.

In you're list node code, you assume that each node is responsible for the next node (if you destroy a node, all the next nodes will be destroyed too). It can be valid behaviour, it depends on your needs, just be sure it's what you really wants.

What you want is to read the pointer without owning it. Current good practice to do this is to use a raw pointer indicating a "use but don't own" kind of usage to other developers looking at this code (unique_ptr means "if I die, the pointed object dies too"):

```
node* here = nullptr; // it will not own the pointed nodes (don't call delete with this pointer)
here = &first_node(); // assuming first_node() returns a reference to the first node
here = here->next.get(); // to get the next node without owning it: use get() - true in all smart pointers interface
```

Comment: I'm not committed to nodes being responsible for the next, I'm just trying to figure out how to translate between raw pointers and smart pointers and this seemed the most direct. Any suggestions on alternatives?

Comment: Well I guess using shared_ptr would be more expensive but easier to handle. Detaching nodes would then be very easy. That being said, an optimized list implementation would do it with raw pointers and custom node allocation.

Comment: Don't forget about `std::swap`.

Comment: @AlexanderDuchene: The whole point of smart pointers is that they *define* who is "responsible" for them. If you want some other object to be responsible for them, you shouldn't use smart pointers.